# Replace character only when followed by non numerical character

Tags: sql, ms-access

While trying to Replace a string in access, I have come across the following issue:

I have a column named "Adres" in a table named "tbl_iopunt"

In this column there are a few different adress type possibilities

Examples:

- I12.1
- IW23.7
- Q.15.3

Now I would like to use a replace query:

```
Expr:  Replace([Adres];"I";"E")
```

However, I only want to replace the "I" to "E" But leave the "IW" adresses untouched.

What would be the best way for me to do this?

Comment: Have a look for MS Access regular expressions (regex).

Comment: Do you mean only when followed by numeric? IW is two alpha, but the first line is alpha then numeric. `UPDATE atable As t SET t.Adres = replace([Adres],"I","E")
WHERE t.Adres Like "i#*"`

Comment: Aah so the "#" makes sure that it only changes the I if it is followed by a numeric character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on how fixed the data are.  If it is only a handlful of cases like "IW" then you would use an Immediate If (IIF), like this:

```
Expr: expr: IIF((Left([Adres],2)="IW"), [Adres], (Replace([Adres],"I","E")))
```